# How would I write a bootloader to load a c kernel?

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, nasm, bootloader

I am learning NASM as I write bootloaders. So far I have a hello world bootloader. I want to know how to link a c program to it and have the bootloader load it into memory and start executing it's entry point function. I need NASM code as I am a NASM n00b. Thank you very much for you help.

EDIT: Basically I need to know how to link the c program and I need NASM code to tsrat it's entry point function. Any gotchas I should know about?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What problems did you have?

Comment: Nope. Just don't know how to link and load it. Google didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although [this tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/C++_Bare_Bones) is for C++, its the exact same procedure (the tutorial lists the parts that are C++ specific, which are just the static ctors & dtors).

when ever your are having problems in this area, [osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) generally has the answer or a tutorial

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of gotchas about booting a kernel:

Here is a good resource http://linuxgazette.net/issue77/krishnakumar.html

that should get you started.

Comment: That's a c program to copy a bootloader onto a floppy. I need a bootloader to start a kernel. I used dd to copy my bootloader.

Comment: fair enough :) i think you got the answer above

Comment: actually if you read all of it it does have boot loader assembly